# freemarker null handling in intermediate expressions

Tags: freemarker

I just wonder if there is any simple and convinient way of handling possible null values in intermediate object in an expresssion:

```
request.service.contact.phone
```

I tried to surround it with (), but it did not work, when for example contact was null:

```
InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
(request.service.contact.phone)!
```

I tried to escape each object, but FM thought that following expression part is builtin

```
ParseException: Unknown built-in variable: phone
request.service!.contact!.phone!
```

I will need to add conditionals but I do not like multiple `if` nesting. Is there something smarter?

Comment: `(request.service.contact.phone)!` should work. I don't remember ever seeing it to fail like that. Is there anything particular with the `ObjectWrapper`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I will try again on Monday. But I expected that it will work though I received exception.

Comment: I tried it again and it works now as you described. There might be a problem that the object was different than I expected (CXF mixed two different arguments into single) and intermedial property did not exist. But when I try to do typo in expression to simulate original error, I receive different (and relevant) exception. So it seems that everything is OK with Freemarker.

Comment: Why did somebody downvote? Hint for downvoting: "This question does show any effort, it is unclear or not useful".